# Transferring materials made in Cycles Render to Blender Game Engine

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, game-engine

I have a question about importing objects painted in cycles render to a blender game engine file.

I've just finished my model and want to put it in a game. I textured, rigged and animated it in the cycles render. When I switch to the blender game engine, everything works fine, but my model's textures and material didn't transfer over. Do I have to texture it again in blender's game engine or can I just import the model into a blender game engine file?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Cycles materials in game engines](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90740/cycles-materials-in-game-engines)

Comment: related: [Materials don't work when switching from Cycles Render to Blender Game](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/95510/materials-dont-work-when-switching-from-cycles-render-to-blender-game) and [Convert Materials from Cycles to Blender Internal Render](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13610/convert-materials-from-cycles-to-blender-internal-render) and [Is it possible to create a game in Blender Cycles Mode?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82475/is-it-possible-to-create-a-game-in-blender-cycles-mode/82599#82599)

Answer (score 2):

Cycles and the BGE don't share the same (or even remotely similar) material systems, and the materials are not transferable between engines. That means you will have to create a new material when switching engines. However, if you have any image textures or any other non-procedural data you can reuse them, you will just have to set up the materials to use the texture.